# Getting "Regular expression is invalid: missing )" error using json in MongoDb

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoose, jongo

I am running the query given below.

```
db.CollectionName.find({'serviceName':{'$regex':'^(ALBUMIN$','$options':'si'}})
```

I am getting the following error.

```
Error: error: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Regular expression is invalid: missing )",
    "code" : 2,
    "codeName" : "BadValue"
}
```

How can I avoid this error since bracket can be anywhere inside the string?
Like- (ALBUMIN  or ((ALBUMIN) etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the **(** character. You can use **\** for escaping special characters in a regex. So for your case it would be like

```
db.CollectionName.find({'serviceName':{'$regex':'^\\(ALBUMIN$','$options':'si'}})
```

You can always test your regular expressions on https://regex101.com/ whenever you use it.

Comment: I tried your solution but still i am getting the same error.

Comment: Aah I just missed that in javascript you need to have \\ for considering it as one. Basically we need to escape \ as well in javascript. I have edited my answer